# Delphi Scoping - Sharing Data between code

Tags: delphi, scope

Delphi XE6 - I have a Unit (EMAIL1.pas) which does related processing.  This is meant to be a standalone unit I can incorporate into multiple programs. My initial procedure is called GetDetailsFromEmailAddress.  It has two parameters, an email address which I lookup and a "group of data" which will get updated, currently defined as a var.  This can be a record or a class, I don't really care.  It is just a group of related strings (firstname, last name, city, etc).  Let's call this EmpRec.

My challenge is that this procedure creates an instance of a class (JEDI VCL HTMLParser) which uses a method pointer to call a method (TableKeyFound).  This routine needs to update EmpRec. I do not want to change this code (HTMLPArser routine) to add additional parameters.  There are several other procedures that my UNIT creates.  All of them need to read/update EmpRec.  How do I do this?

I need a way to "promote" the variable EmpRec which is passed in this one routine (GetDetailsFromEmailAddress) to be GLOBAL within this UNIT so that all the routines can access or change the various elements.  How do I go about this?  I do NOT really want to have to define this as a GLOBAL / Application wide variable.

Code sample below.  So.. How does the routine TableKeyFoundEx get access to the EmpRec variable?

```
procedure GetDetailsFromEmailAddress(Email: string; var EmpRec: TEmpRec);
begin
...
 // Now create the HTML Parser...
    JvHtmlParser1 := TJvHTMLParser.Create(nil);
 // On event KeyFoundEx, call Parsehandlers.TableKeyFoundEx;
    JvHtmlParser1.OnKeyFoundEx := ParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx;
    ...
end.


procedure TParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx(Sender: TObject; Key, Results, OriginalLine: String; TagInfo: TTagInfo;
  Attributes: TStrings);
 begin
..
// NEED ACCESS to EmpRec here, but can't change procedure definition
end;
```

Comment: Please show some code rather than describing it

Comment: ...done... Code above

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways I would approach this:

1. use the parser's `Tag` property:

   ```
   procedure GetDetailsFromEmailAddress(Email: string; var EmpRec: TEmpRec);
   begin
     ...
     JvHtmlParser1 := TJvHTMLParser.Create(nil);
     JvHtmlParser1.OnKeyFoundEx := ParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx;
     JvHtmlParser1.Tag := NativeInt(@EmpRec);
     ...
   end;

   procedure TParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx(Sender: TObject; Key, Results, OriginalLine: String; TagInfo: TTagInfo; Attributes: TStrings);
   var
     EmpRec: PEmpRec; // assuming PEmpRec = ^TEmpRec
   begin
     EmpRec := PEmpRec(TJvHTMLParser(Sender).Tag);
     ...
   end;
   ```
2. use a little `TMethod` hack to pass the record DIRECTLY to the event handler:

   ```
   // Note: this is declared as a STANDALONE procedure instead of a class method.
   // The extra DATA parameter is where a method would normally pass its 'Self' pointer...
   procedure TableKeyFoundEx(Data: Pointer: Sender: TObject; Key, Results, OriginalLine: String; TagInfo: TTagInfo; Attributes: TStrings);
   var
     EmpRec: PEmpRec; // assuming PEmpRec = ^TEmpRec
   begin
     EmpRec := PEmpRec(Data);
     ...
   end;

   procedure GetDetailsFromEmailAddress(Email: string; var EmpRec: TEmpRec);
   var
     M: TMethod;
   begin
     ...
     JvHtmlParser1 := TJvHTMLParser.Create(nil);
     M.Code := @TableKeyFoundEx;
     M.Data := @EmpRec;
     JvHtmlParser1.OnKeyFoundEx := TJvKeyFoundExEvent(M);
     ...
   end;
   ```

Comment: The TableKeyFoundEx routine is a method that is defined as part of the THTMLParser unit that comes with the JEDI library. (i.e. all the parameters are predefined). I am really hesitant to mess around with their code unless it is a last resort.

Comment: Did I say you had to mess around with JEDI's code?  No, you do not.  The second example is using the existing parameters, it is simply hijacking Delphi's implicit `Self` parameter to pass the record pointer instead of a class object pointer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. First you say that you don't want to mess with the JEDI's code but then you want their code to update some data object defined in your code. Now how can their code upate your block of code without their code being changed? Also if you are just extending the functionality of their code and don't want your changes to cause backward compatibility the right path would be overriding their method with your own. So then you are calling your overriden method wile rest of the JCL will still be calling their original method.

Comment: Because I am dynamically creating an object which they (JEDI) defines (HTMLParser), I am having to dynamically "attach" an event to the HTMLParser.  This event is basically the "I found an HTML Keyword" event.  I don't want to change the class definition of this event. As such, I cannot pass my structure of keywords to the event. So how do I do this?  It obviously CAN be done because Remy and David have shown me 3 different ways to do this.  Subclassing appears to the simplest/most elegant way of achieving my goal.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two options that Remy offers, you could derive a sub-class of `TJvHTMLParser`.

```
type
  PEmpRec = ^TEmpRec;      

  TMyJvHTMLParser = class(TJvHTMLParser)
  private
    FEmpRec: PEmpRec;
  public
    constructor Create(EmpRec: PEmpRec);
  end;

....

constructor TMyJvHTMLParser.Create(EmpRec: PEmpRec);
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
  FEmpRec := EmpRec;
end;
```

When you create the parser, do so like this:

```
procedure GetDetailsFromEmailAddress(Email: string; var EmpRec: TEmpRec);
var
  Parser: TMyJvHTMLParser;
begin
  Parser := TMyJvHTMLParser.Create(@EmpRec);
  try
    Parser.OnKeyFoundEx := ParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx;
    ....
  finally
    Parser.Free;
  end;
end.
```

And in your `OnKeyFoundEx` you cast `Sender` back to the parser type to gain access to the record:

```
procedure TParseHandlers.TableKeyFoundEx(Sender: TObject; ...);
var
  EmpRec: PEmpRec;
begin
  EmpRec := (Sender as TMyJvHTMLParser).FEmpRec;
  ....
end;
```